# Segmenting products on the shelf

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect edges from the products on a shelf using histogram projections. But I am stuck at 2 levels.

The challenges that I m facing are:

1. How to get the longest non shelf segment from the image i.e Detect the width of the widest product on the shelf from the available one.
2. How to achieve morphological reconstruction using custom markers.To eliminate

all small horizontal segments, I am generating 2 markers which can be seen in 'markers.png' (Attached). With them, I am calculating the minimum of the reconstruction outputs from both the markers.

```
Need assistance on this.
Thanks a lot
Below is my python code for the same.
Below is my python code

********************************************************************************

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

# Read the input image
img = cv.imread('C:\\Users\\672059\\Desktop\\p2.png')
# Converting from BGR to RGB. Default is BGR.
# img_rgb = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# Resize the image to 150,150
img_resize = cv.resize(img, (150, 150))
# Get the dimensions of the image
img_h, img_w, img_c = img_resize.shape
# Split the image on channels
red = img[:, :, 0]
green = img[:, :, 1]
blue = img[:, :, 2]

# Defining a vse for erosion
vse = np.ones((img_h, img_w), dtype=np.uint8)

# Morphological Erosion for red channel
red_erode = cv.erode(red, vse, iterations=1)
grad_red = cv.subtract(red, red_erode)
# Morphological Erosion for green channel
green_erode = cv.erode(green, vse, iterations=1)
grad_green = cv.subtract(green, green_erode)
# Morphological Erosion for blue channel
blue_erode = cv.erode(blue, vse, iterations=1)
grad_blue = cv.subtract(blue, blue_erode)

# Stacking the individual channels into one processed image
grad = [grad_red, grad_green, grad_blue]
retrieved_img = np.stack(grad, axis=-1)
retrieved_img = retrieved_img.astype(np.uint8)
retrieved_img_gray = cv.cvtColor(retrieved_img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.title('Figure 1')
plt.imshow(cv.bitwise_not(retrieved_img_gray), cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
plt.show()

# Hough Transform of the image to get the longest non shelf boundary from the image!
edges = cv.Canny(retrieved_img_gray, 127, 255)
minLineLength = img_w
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 127, minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=1)
temp = img.copy()
l = []
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[x]:
        cv.line(temp, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        d = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
        l.append(d)

# Defining a hse for erosion
hse = np.ones((1, 7), dtype=np.uint8)
opening = cv.morphologyEx(retrieved_img_gray, cv.MORPH_OPEN, hse)
plt.title('Figure 2')
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2), plt.imshow(cv.bitwise_not(opening), 'gray')
plt.show()

# Dilation with disk shaped structuring element
horizontal_size = 7
horizontalstructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (horizontal_size, 1))
dilation = cv.dilate(opening, horizontalstructure)
plt.title('Figure 3')
plt.imshow(cv.bitwise_not(dilation), 'gray')
plt.show()
# Doing canny edge on dilated image
edge = cv.Canny(dilation, 127, 255)
plt.title('Figure 4')
plt.imshow(edges, cmap='gray')
plt.show()

h_projection = edge.sum(axis=1)
print(h_projection)
plt.title('Projection')
plt.plot(h_projection)
plt.show()


listing = []
for i in range(1, len(h_projection)-1):
    if h_projection[i-1] == 0 and h_projection[i] == 0:
        listing.append(dilation[i])
        listing.append(dilation[i-1])
        a = np.array([np.array(b) for b in l])
        h = len(l)
        _, contours, _ = cv.findContours(a, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(contours[0])
        y = y + i - h
        cv.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        l.clear()

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

# Generating a mask
black_bg = np.ones([img_h, img_w], dtype=np.uint8)
# Clone the black bgd image
left = black_bg.copy()
right = black_bg.copy()
# Taking 10% of the image width
ten = int(0.1 * img_w)
left[:, 0:ten+1] = 0
right[:, img_w-ten:img_w+1] = 0
plt.title('Figure 4')
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(left, 'gray')
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(right, 'gray')
plt.show()
# Marker = left and right. Mask = dilation
mask = dilation
marker_left = left
marker_right = right
```

---

```
********************************************************************************
```

markers.png link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45WJ6.png

```
********************************************************************************
```

[image]

Comment: Please post an example picture and intermedatie results.

Comment: Hi, I cant upload images, hence providing links.     
    markers.png link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/45WJ6.png
    Input image link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcXpO.png
    Canny Edge Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKnjS.png
    Horizontal Projections Output Link:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL1ac.png
    Detected Edges link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/F95Zc.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on you input image, I would :

- take a picture of an empty fridge
- then compare the current image with the empty one.
- play with morphological operations
- get connected components > size N

If you can't take a empty fridge image:

- segment the shelves (threshold white parts)
- undo do the rotation of the image by using image moments of the shelves
- for each shelve:

  - Threshold on `saturation`
  - Do a vertical projection
  - Count maxima.

Tresholded:

[image]

Erode-dilate:

[image]

Connected componens (width > 10 * height + > minsize):
[image]

And you have shelves.

Now take the average Y form each shelf and cut the original image in pieces:

[image]

Dither to 8 colors:

[image]

and threshold:

[image]

Connected components (h>1.5*w, minsize... this is hard here, I played with it :)

[image]

Comment: Hi RobAu, horizontal segmentation of the image is my first aim. And i am unable to achieve it. Can you help me. I know this may be very primary for some, but i am stucked. Appreciate your help

Comment: I dont understand the concept of connected components here :( Also I wont have any empty fridge image with me. thanks a lot RobAu

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ8q8Bw0AP4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMIrQdX4BkE

Comment: Is the solution generic enough? How do you choose the kernel sizes in morphological operations? I need image independent configurations as far as possible. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What kind of thresholding did you use? I aint fetching similar results to you

Comment: Dont know, I used gimp as I was lazy :) But I've only used simple operations. (First step btw is to convert to grayscale).  If you take a histogram of all colors (and know the shelves are less then 10% of the image) set the limit of the color that is on the border of 10%

Comment: You have added only 1 input image, so it is hard to generalize from that :)

Comment: BTW: the more information you have on your domain, the stricter the operations can be. For example, if you know what kind of drinks you have, you can use their color to model some templates to find them much better.

Comment: Will you please ping the code you have used for this :) Thanks a lot. I am confused.

Comment: Sorry, can't do. Take the examples,  and find your solution!

Comment: I have been working long on this. Please help me out by providing your code so that i can understand the flow better and fast. Thanks

Comment: You approach is not generic enough :( It fails on most of the images. Can you please suggest any other approach. I cant attach an image:(

Comment: @Hrishikeshlele just add the link

Comment: You can check out these images-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiA90.jpg, https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TlRQ.jpg. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. This is real hard to generalize! As in; master thesis worthy I guess :)

Comment: I have a thought. If I want to reduce the scope of this project, what can be the best approach. I feel if the scope is minimised, I can work out.